# Prime numbers that lead to relatively prime

Tags: nt.number-theory

It might be well-known (and sorry if it is), but a quick search did not return the answer.

Consider prime numbers $p \neq q$.

Are $\displaystyle \frac{p^q-1}{p-1}$ and $\displaystyle  \frac{q^p-1}{q-1}$ relatively prime?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feit-Thompson_conjecture .

Comment: I've deleted my comment, which was incorrect and apologize to Portland for my flippancy. 

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer is no.  As the Wikipedia article in my comment states, the counterexample $p = 17, q = 3313$ was found by Stephens in 1971, but the stronger question of whether one can ever divide the other is a famous open problem because its solution would greatly simplify a step in the proof of the Feit-Thompson theorem.

Comment: See also Karl Dilcher and Joshua Knauer, On a conjecture of Feit and Thompson, in High primes and misdemeanors, Fields Inst Commun 41 (2004) 169-178, MR 2005c:11003, where it is confirmed that the Stephens example is still the only one known (as of the date of the publication, of course), and where details are provided about the scope of the search for more examples. 

Comment: I've just check all pairs $p,q\leq 1000$th prime out of curiosity...